# How to share a mongoose connection across child processes?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, connection-pooling, child-process

I have the following db.js module, taking care of mongoose connection:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(config) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    //mongoose.connect(config.connectionString);
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.open(config.server, config.database, config.port, {user: config.user, pass: config.password});
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', console.log.bind(console, 'connected to database server ' + config.server));
};
```

In my app.js, I simply call `var db = require('./db')(config.db);`, and all the models in my application work well.

For some background jobs, I'm forking a bunch of child processes (using [worker-farm](https://npmjs.org/package/worker-farm)), and since I did not know how to pass on the connection object (or whether it's even allowed), I opened a connection in each (calling db.js).

The problem is, after a while I'm starting to experience an error from each of the child processes: `{ [Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.] state: 1 }`. Furthermore, since this causes an unexpectedExcption in those child processes, worker-farm restarts them - and it all gets stuck in a big infinite loop of horror (yes, I can solve the loop - but I'd rather solve the problem :)).

What am I doing wrong? What's the best way to share a mongoose connection across a pool of workers?

Comment: Do the forked processes close the connection ever? The error could happen if you've closed the connection before all work has been completed.

Comment: No, they don't close the connection